# How to get device details of office 365 users

Tags: office365, office365api

We are implementing an integration with office 365 from our product. For that, we wanted to get the device details of the users in an office 365. For instance, if a user is using office in 5 of his workstations, we wanted to get detail about those workstations - name, IP, MAC, Serial no etc. 
Is there a way of getting these information through Rest API? We could not figure out one yet.
Is there a way of getting this throuh any powershell modules - like MSOnline and MSOnlineExtended.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#DeviceEntity << There's a device entity in the Azure AD Graph API with properties like deviceOSType, devicePhysicalIds, etc.